# Como salvar dados bancários na base de dados?

Tags: mysql, laravel, criptografia

Ao fazer uma loja virtual qual a melhor maneira de salvar dados bancários do usuário na base de dados?

O número do cartão de crédito, número de segurança e a data de validade.

Por exemplo, usando o Laravel. Usaria um tipo de criptografia como o `bcrypt`?

Acontece que o `bcrypt` é one-way, então não teria como eu mostrar em uma possível tela os dados bancários do usuário para ele fazer uma outra compra usando os mesmos dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diego,

Dependendo do tamanho da sua loja virtual eu não recomendaria você ter a responsabilidade sobre esses dados, em caso de um possível problema externo (invasão, falha de segurança do servidor e etc), entendo que é ruim para o usuário ter que digitar o dados toda vez que for pagar, mas creio que será menos estressante do que uma possível auditoria, ou processos judicias.

O que poderia recomendar seria usar algumas opções como o:

- [**Mercado Pago**](https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/)
- [**PagSeguro**](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/)
- [**PayU**](http://developers.payulatam.com/pt/api/)

> Existem outras opções, só mencionei esses *porque foram os que lembrei* e por conta de ter uma boa
>   documentação até mesmo em português.

Mas caso realmente queira salvar os dados no seu banco, utilizar o [`crypt();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) possa ser a melhor opção, ele tem algumas limitações de tamanho, e não é muito recomendado usar em senhas *(segundo a documentação)*, mas se adequaria bem a seu caso pelo menos nas informações do usuário.

Tem esse artigo aqui do [Thiago de Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografando-senhas-no-php-usando-bcrypt-blowfish), é antigo, porem da uma boa base do `crypt();`

Em resumo, comece jogando a responsabilidade para empresas terceirizadas, conforme for crescendo você vai tomando tomando responsabilidade dessas informações.

Comment: E a Pagar.me, será que é boa?

Comment: @DiegoSouza o pagar.me é uma novidade pra mim vou até guarda-lo, o site realmente é bonito, e gostei bastante da documentação, eu só não achei as taxas dele, mas parece ser uma plataforma completa.

Comment: Parece que as taxas são nos mesmos moldes da PaYU.